# Как проверить права программы?

Tags: python, linux, windows

Есть ли мультиплатформенное решение по проверке прав программы? На Linux - это проверка запуска от root пользователя, есть ли подобное на Windows?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, имеет ли пользователь доступ к определенному бинарному файлу?

Comment: Нет, имеет ли пользователь права администратора в системе.

Comment: «Права администратора» — понятие растяжимое, даже в линуксе администратор совсем не обязательно должен иметь доступ к root

Comment: в линуксе с полкитом сало всё чудеснее и мудрёнее) 5+ механизмов контроля доступа у не-администратора

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для Windows:

```py
import pythoncom
import pywintypes
import win32api
from win32com.shell import shell

if shell.IsUserAnAdmin():
   ...
```

Источник: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946746/python-checking-if-a-user-has-administrator-privileges/2946788#2946788).